# i have an iPhone 4s but can't download songs

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

I'm getting trouble with my iPhone 4s. I don't have songs in the iPhone. I've tried many time but I can't find the perfect answer.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Do you have troubles using iTunes, are you looking for solutions allowing to download (and play) tracks directly on the phone, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple phone's does't support downloading option we have only choice to download apple software in our PC and copy it from my mobile